# Does this local ring have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ring-theory, local-rings

I came up with this:

Let $S=\{(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\:|\:a_n\in \mathbb{C}, (a_n)_{n\geq 1}\text{ converges}\}$ be the set of convergent complex sequences. Then this set forms a ring under pointwise operations, with the multiplicative identity given by the constant sequence $1,1,\dots$, and the additive identity given by $0,0,\dots$.

Let $S_0=\{(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\in S\:|\:\text{for sufficiently large }n, a_n=0\}$ be the set of sequences that are "eventually $0$". Then $S_0$ is an ideal in $S$.

Define $\overline{S}=S/S_0$, and for each sequence $s\in S$, write $\overline{s}=s+S_0\in\overline{S}$. Then two sequences $s_1,s_2\in S$ are equal in $\overline{S}$ if they are "eventually identical".

Define $L:\overline{S}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by $L(\overline{s})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s$. This map is well-defined, because if $\overline{s_1}=\overline{s_2}$, then $s_1$ and $s_2$ are "eventually" the same, so they have the same limit. By the familiar limit rules, $L$ is a ring homomorphism that maps unity to unity.

Let $I\subseteq\overline{S}$ be the kernel of this map. Of course, $I$ is a proper ideal.

Let $s\in S$ be a sequence that *does not* converge to $0$, so that means $\overline{s}\in\overline{S}\setminus I$. Then for all sufficiently large $n$, $s_n\neq 0$. So it is possible to form a sequence $s'$ such that for all sufficiently large $n$, $s'_n=1/s_n$. This means that the sequence $ss'$ is "eventually" $1$, and thus $\overline{s}$ is a unit in $\overline{S}$.

What I have just shown is that every element in $\overline{S}\setminus I$ is a unit, and since $I$ is a proper ideal, every element in $I$ is *not* a unit. Thus, $I$ is the unique maximal ideal in $\overline{S}$, which means that $\overline{S}$ is actually a *local* ring, which is nice.

Is there a name for this construction? I don't think it tells us anything new about convergent sequences of complex numbers, it's just a nice way to "repackage" what we know about convergent sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construction of this local ring is an instance of the following more general observation:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $p \in X$. Then the ring of [germs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)) of continuous functions at $p$ is local with maximal ideal $\{f : f(p)=0\}$.

Indeed, a convergent sequence (say, with values in $\mathbb{C}$) is the same as a continuous map
$$\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\} \to \mathbb{C},$$
where $\infty$ is mapped to the limit of the sequence. Here, $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ has the topology in which $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete and the sets $\mathbb{N}_{\geq n} \cup \{\infty\}$ form a basis of the neighborhoods of $\infty$. Thus, continuity is precisely the limit condition. In other words, $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ is the [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the discrete space $\mathbb{N}$. A germ of a continuous function at $\infty$ is therefore a convergent sequence (defined on some $\mathbb{N}_{\geq n} \cup \{\infty\}$, but we can extend randomly on $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$), where two such sequences are identified when they are eventually the same. The observation tells us that these form a local ring, and that the maximal ideal consists of the sequences that converge to $0$.

So, the answer to your question "Does this local ring have a name?" is: Yes, it is the ring of germs of continous functions on the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ at $\infty$.

The mentioned general observation precisely says that the [stalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalk_(sheaf)) of the [sheaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)) of continuous functions on a space at every point is a local ring, that is, $(X,C(-))$ is a [locally ringed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_space).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm sorry to say I don't know any of those words, so forgive me for asking this slightly rude question: is there any use in describing complex sequences in this way -- does it make it easier to prove certain facts about them -- or is this just a nice way to "package" what we already know about complex sequences? 

More rudely: is this just sophisticated verbiage, or is it good for something?

Comment: No worries. That's exactly why I linked the Wikipedia articles where one can learn more about all these notions. About your follow-up question: I am not sure. The facts that you are repackaging are useful for sure, and it is always good to have the more general picture in mind. But I would be surprised if you can prove anything about convergent sequences with this interpretation which you cannot prove directly. For me, the point of my answer is that it is *no coincidence* that you get a local ring like you described. It is part of a more general lemma about germs of continuous functions.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more approachable.

Comment: Thank you! I understand better now.